# How to get "random" number based on a string in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, random

I know there are plenty of random number generators out there, but I am looking for something that may be a little more predictable. Is there a way to get a "random" number (one that would be the same in every instance) given a string? I would like to do this in bash. I am looking for something a little more advanced than the count of characters in the string, but not as advanced as a full checksum of it.

The end goal is to get a decimal value, so this could be ran against a string multiple times repeating the result.

Comment: Why not use a hash function like `md5sum` or `sha1sum`? `echo -n "Hello World" | md5sum`.

Comment: I agree, a hash is probably easiest; I use one for a similar purpose myself.

Comment: You said "not as advanced as a full checksum".  Why?  `sha1sum` is easy enough to use.

Comment: In what range?  What are you going to use the number for?

Comment: So a checksum is the best way to do this? I was hoping to get a decimal value, so couldn't the checksum value get turned into a decimal?

Comment: @ghostdog74: `$RANDOM` doesn't meet the requirements; the OP is looking for something that's repeatable for a given string.

Comment: Yup, that's right. Hey just have to ask, is there a better word for this operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a random number, but you don't want a full checksum, it's **contradiction**. I think `md5sum` and `sha1sum` is really easy to use and should fit your needs:

```
md5sum <<< "$your_str"
```

or

```
sha1sum <<< "$your_str"
```

Update:

If you need decimal numbers, just:

```
n=$(md5sum <<< "$your_str")
echo $((0x${n%% *}))
```

Comment: Just what I'm looking for. Thanks Mu.

Comment: `md5sum <<< "$your_str"` uses the [<<< herestring](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) bash functionality. `${n%% *}` extracts the first of the 2 fields returned by md5sum, which is the md5 hash. It does this by [deleting the longest match of the substring](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) " *" from the end of the variable. `$((0x________))` converts the hexadecimal md5sum from hex (base 16) to decimal (base 10)

Answer (score 7):

To hash the string `abc` to 3 decimals:

```
echo $((0x$(echo abc | md5sum | cut -f 1 -d " " | cut -c 1-3))) | cut -c 1-3
```

To get e.g. 4 decimals instead of 3, replace the two occurrences of `3` by `4`:

```
echo $((0x$(echo abc | md5sum | cut -f 1 -d " " | cut -c 1-4))) | cut -c 1-4
```

- `$(echo abc | md5sum | cut -f 1 -d " " | cut -c 1-4)` gives an hexadecimal of 4 digits.
- `$((0xHEX))` converts an hexadecimal (`HEX`) to decimal, which may have more than 4 digits even when `HEX` has 4 digits, e.g. `ffff` is `65535`.
- `cut -c 1-4` gets the first 4 digits.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo abc | md5sum | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]{3}"  | head -n1
Result -> 248
$ echo xyz | md5sum | grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]{3}"  | head -n1
Result -> 627
```

Combined other answers!

For HEX colors

```
echo abc | sha1sum | grep -Eo "[a-f0-9]{6}"  | head -n1
03cfd7
echo abc | sha256sum | grep -Eo "[a-f0-9]{6}"  | head -n1
edeaaf
echo abc | sha512sum | grep -Eo "[a-f0-9]{6}"  | head -n1
4f285d
```

Comment: The first solution for 3 digits fails in (rare) cases where the hash has no 3 consecutive decimals. See my solution for an approach that always returns 3 decimals.